# Android Sherlock Fragment webview issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-webview

Based on this reference http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implement-swiping-between-tabs-with-viewpager-in-action-bar-using-sherlock-library/

I am using tabs with sherlock fragments ie in one tab, when i try to use webview, the link is not displaying.It keeps scrolling and not displaying the content.

public class AppleFragment extends SherlockFragment{
    WebView w;

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web, container, false);
     w=(WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
     w.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
      w.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
      w.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
      w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
          return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

}       
@Override
public void onStart() {     
    super.onStart();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add this code and get the results

```
w.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

}
```